# Automapper Remove Prefix Per Map

Tags: c#, automapper

I want to remove a prefix from my source object, but I'd like to do it for each map an not globally, as it could cause issues where it's removing a column when it shouldn't. Is there an easy way to do this? This is what I'm working with right now

```
public partial class MappingProfile : Profile
{


    public MappingProfile()
    {
        //I would prefer this not to be a global and only remove the prefix on the specific map below
        RecognizePrefixes("Can");
        CreateMap<Candidate, CandidateVM>();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can have a separate profile where you set the prefix.